# Linux Mint messes up desktop icons with dual screen

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor

I use Linux Mint and have two screens in use. One is connected via CGA, the other via an HDMI<->VGA adapter.
I used ARandR to set these two up and it works fine. But everytime I restart my computer, the desktop icons are totally messed up and shifted over the upper limit of the screen. I think there are even some of them that I cannot reach anymore.
What can I do here?

The left screen is horizontally, the right one vertically.
Here is a screenshot of the left one:
[image]

SOLUTION:
I had to shift the left screen more up in ARandR.
This is how it should look:
[image]

Comment: I think, it is more of a RandR issue, Mint works perfectly fine with multi-display if using preferred WMs like Cinnamon, Mate or Xfce. Did you try them? But CGA-VGA? Seriously? Last time I saw CGA was 96 or 97...

Comment: [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/740349/edit) the question and add a screenshot of your current ArandR window so the screen placement and orientation is known.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting the left screen with ARandR was the problem. This is how I solved it:
[image]

Comment: Lol yeah - the same workaround I use :-D Less-than-ideal, IMO, but workable. I hope this solves it for you permanently.